# The idiomatic way of saying stealing time

Tags: meaning, idioms, idiom-requests, idiom-meaning

What is the idiomatic way of saying 'stealing time', if someone is so busy and he wants to work on something by sneaking to it?

Comment: Idiomatically, we just say we'll ***make*** time [to do something, even though we're very busy with other things]. More extreme metaphoric usages like ***steal*** or ***pinch*** aren't in common use.

Comment: How about 'to skive off' - which is used in British English, but is almost slang.

Answer (score 6):

One can actually say "I managed to steal a few precious moments / minutes / hours with my family."

> “To my delight, before the graduation ceremony began, I was able to
> steal a few minutes with an old friend.”

...........

> To "steal" time in this way is to be able to assign, set aside, or
> reserve that time for a particular reason or activity. The presumption
> is that there other demands for this time.

[[bibliolept; WordReference.com](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/steal-a-few-minutes.3507525/)

So "I was able to steal a few a few short hours away from my job to ..." (usually used in a past time-frame).

Comment: "I am stealing time from my job to answer stack exchange queries" or  "I will be able to steal away early tomorrow' would be normal idiomatic usage, so I am not sure that it is  correct to say it is usually used usually in a past time frame.

Comment: @AndyM - But *usually* doesn’t mean *only*.  Your examples demonstrate why *only* would have been incorrect.  To disprove *usually* you’d need to show frequency of use data.

Comment: It's usually used conversationally, and a past time-frame disarms the word 'steal' somewhat (no obvious ill consequences).

Comment: Google Ngram suggests that 'Steal an hour'  is twice as common as 'Stole an hour', which suggests that past case is less common usage. Not proof, but equally no evidence has been offered for the past case being more common. Interestingly suggests that the all forms of the phrase were more common in the 1800s and have declined since.

Comment: I've checked the obvious ngrams. Most of the recent returns for 'steal an hour' seem to be old-fashioned, and/or non-present  ('they'd arrive at the same time all unbidden to steal an hour or two'), and/or modal constructions ('Even then , whenever she could steal an hour or two') .... // Raw Google hits: "I will steal an hour" -"from days gone by": about 5 hits // "I stole an hour" -"from days gone by" :1270000 hits. This again doesn't **prove** the claim above. But the metaphhorical use of 'steal' here has a literary flavour, this most commonly associated with a past time-frame.

Answer (score 1):

**On the sly**

> on the sly
> PHRASE ​INFORMAL
> DEFINITIONS
> 1 done secretly, especially because you know you should not be doing
> it
> *I’m supposed to be on a diet, but I still have the odd candy bar on
> the sly.*

Macmillan : on the sly
https://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/on-the-sly

---

> And on the sly, she focused on the interesting stuff. She made her bones as a news and feature writer, editor, and translator, especially of literature. Font screams in her sleep, disturbed by eerie nightmares.

from the *about the author* section of Silvia font's *Musings on the Dark*.